# How can I give priority to one helper in Zend Framework?

Tags: php, zend-framework, action, helper, zend-controller

I have the following code:

```
    public function _setHelpers() {
        Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addPrefix('My_Controller_Action_Helpers');
        Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addPath ( APPLICATION_PATH . '/controllers/helpers' );
    }
```

With this I can add a helper wether in My/Controller/Action/Helpers/Helper.php or /application/controllers/helpers/Helper.php. That is ok, however I need to gave priority to the one in /application/, that is: if I have both helpers load the one in /application and not the one in My/Controller/...

**EDITING**

I was able to fix this by changing the code to this:

```
    public function _setHelpers() {
    $prefix = 'My_Controller_Action_Helpers';
    Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addPrefix ( $prefix );
    Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addPath ( APPLICATION_PATH . '/controllers/helpers', 'My_Controller_Action_Helper' );
    return $this;
}
```

As you may notice, its almost the same, with the difference that when adding the path I added also the prefix. Thanks to all for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Plugin paths added to the Helper Broker use `Zend_Loader_PluginLoader` which uses a LIFO stack for paths, so that is the last path added is the first one checked.  Given your code, since you are adding the `application` path second, it should have priority over the files in `My/Controller` (both `addPrefix` and `addPath` call the same method in `Zend_Loader_PluginLoader` so they are effectively the same thing.

Is this not what you are finding?

Comment: Actually no, I have this two codes:

`class My_Controller_Action_Helpers_Noticia extends My_Controller_Action_Helper_Abstract {
 protected function _direct() {
  echo 1;
 }
}

class My_Controller_Action_Helper_Noticia extends Busca_Controller_Action_Helpers_Noticia {
 protected function _direct() {
  echo 2;
 }
}`

The first one is My/Controller/... and the second one in Controllers/Helpers/

And it shows 1 in the view...

Comment: In that case the reason is because one of the classes isn't named correctly so it won't be loaded.  Depending on your app prefix, I think you have to change the one in `Controllers/Helpers` to be called `Busca_Controller_Action_Helper_Noticia` and make sure the location is `application/controllers/action/helpers/Noticia.php`

Comment: The thing is that it was allright, the problem was other, but I already figure it out. Thanks for your help, you give me the clue to fix it (since I printed the prefix was being added to Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getPluginLoader ()->getPaths () and in that way I saw the need of add also the prefix to addPath)

Thanks a lot!